# Font Awesome 5 icon's class binding change doesn't affect the icon

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome, aurelia, font-awesome-5

During the upgrade process of Font Awesome 5 from 4.7.0, I noticed that any class bindings I gave to an `<i>` tag would not function as it did before.

Imagine the following element with a class binding:

`<i class.bind="iconClass"></i>`

And imagine the initial value of the `iconClass` being `'fas fa-cog'`. When changing the value of `iconClass` to `'fas fa-ship'`, the icon won't update to the newly set icon classes. It will remain a **cog** icon.

I believe this happens because Font Awesome 5 replaces the `<i>` tags with `<svg>` tags and doesn't copy over the class binding properly and thus not trigger an icon change.

In the following example, the bound classes are changed after two seconds to illustrate the problem, please see [this GistRun](https://gist.run/?id=672fbb164896cc72d0ed61d494ed04c2) for an example of the issue. See `app.html` and `app.js` for the implementation. It also contains a dirty workaround.

How can/should this behaviour be implemented?

Comment: [There is an upgrade document](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4). Was it not useful?

Comment: @Andy The upgrade document doesn't address this problem, so no.

Comment: I have also tried using the `FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: 'nest' }` setting. The `<svg>` gets nested within the `<i>` element. However, the SVG icon doesn't change even though the `<i>` element's class binding has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by the answer of @huocp utilising `innerhtml`.

Using a custom component to solve this problem does indeed work. However, as I will only be having one icon with a class binding in my project, I have found a simpler way of doing this:

`<i innerhtml="<i class='${iconClass}'></i>"></i>`

A change of the `iconClass` value will generate a new `<i>` child (while replacing the old `<svg>` element) within the parent, after which Font Awesome 5 will convert this `<i>` child into an `<svg>`.

Any elements can be used as parent and child elements of course, I just think `<i>` looks short and clean, it will nest the `<svg>` generated by Font Awesome 5 within the `<i>`.

Comment: :-) great. That is easy.

Answer (score 2):

See working gistrun here: https://gist.run/?id=55559f3bd606aa854502f3ddbbcad480

Use this custom component like this.

```
<fa-svg icon-class.bind="iconClass"></fa-svg>
```

fa-svg.js

```
import {inject, inlineView, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
@inlineView("<template></template>")
export class FaSvg {
  @bindable iconClass;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  iconClassChanged(newIcon) {
    if (!this.live) return;
    this._rebuild(newIcon);
  }

  attached() {
    this.live = true;
    this._rebuild(this.iconClass);
  }

  detached() {
    this.live = false;
  }

  _rebuild(iconClass) {
    this.element.innerHTML = iconClass ? `<i class="${iconClass}"></i>` : '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your component suggestion. I have tried it and it indeed works! However, I have found a simpler solution, see my answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/48922982/4795677

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue before.

As you said, you were using "svg with js" (the fa5 recommended way). It does fight Aurelia since the svg version use JavaScript to replace DOM element, the binding of Aurelia getting destroyed along with old DOM element.

Switch to "web font with css" which fa5 supported perfectly. It will obey your command as fa4.

Comment: Furthermore, "web font" over-all provides better exp for me. "svg" version responds quite differently with line-height and other font related style since it is not really a font in browser's eye.

Comment: This would indeed work as the behaviour would be the same as the old Font Awesome behaviour. However, I would like to have access to the new features introduced with their SVG icons. For example transformations, layering and masking.

Comment: well, that's a trade-off. Currently you don't have a choice given you want to control it with Aurelia.